# Workaround for Google docs stops firing textWillChange for keyboard extensions in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-docs

I'm part of a team that has made a Keyboard Extension with a lot of users using google docs. A recent update of google docs is broken and causes `textWillChange` and `textDidChange` to stop being fired if the user manually moves the cursor around by holding the finger down. If the user closes the keyboard and opens i again it will work until broken again...

Above event are quite important as all suggestions rely on these events in order to update (this goes for all keyboard extensions, also big ones as Swiftkey).

To make matters worse google has stopped giving support of editing documents from the website only supporting edit through apps.

**So my questions are as follows**:

1. So is there any way we can detect this issue has happened?
2. Is there any way we can reenable it when it happens?
3. Is there any way we can avoid it from happening?
4. Where should we report this to google (tried: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/0OsHxzOjTq4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general problem with keyboard-extension in iOS. Different apps react different and sends somewhat different event.